# Value of Form Input not updating on Submit in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React and writing a basic program where using two input fields and a button I want to show the submitted data through another component.
I have declared state in the App component and used a handleChange and handleSubmit method. I have used this state data as props in Display component. But I am getting the data  shown when input changes and not on submit.

Have a look at my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      first:'',
      last:''
    }
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    //this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
//handleChange method will capture the change in the values of input field
//Here [e.target.name]:e.target.value will set the input value to name="first" and name="last"
    handleChange(e){
      this.setState({
      [e.target.name]:e.target.value
      });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
      e.preventdefault();
      this.handleChange();
    }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <div class="row">
       <input name="first" onChange={this.handleChange}type="text" value={this.state.first}></input>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <input name="last" onChange={this.handleChange}type="text" value={this.state.last}></input>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <input  name="submit" type="button" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></input>
       </div>
       <Display name={this.state.first} last={this.state.last}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

const Display=(props)=>{
    return(
      <div>
        <div class="row">
        {props.name}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        {props.last}
        </div>
      </div>
    )

}




export default App;
```

Also can somebody explain me why do we write `[e.target.name]:e.target.value`
in setState and why do we right it as []?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `handleChange` function that you have used sets the state to `first` and `last` states respectively when they change. This pattern is called [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in React.

On why we use `[]` in the `handleChange` function, as you have already pointed out in comments of your code, it is to set the state to `first` and `last`, which are also `name` properties of your inputs. This syntax is called Computed Property and you can find explanation on this in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs).

If you want the `Display` component to pick up the state only when you press submit, the alternative is to maintain two separate states for them. One is for the form and another one is for the validated one that is displayed.

Demo:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      first:'',
      last:''
    }
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
    
  handleSubmit(first, last){
    this.setState({
      first,
      last,
    })
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
       <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
       <Display name={this.state.first} last={this.state.last}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      first:'',
      last:''
    }
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(e){
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
      });
  }
  
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.first, this.state.last);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="row">
       <input name="first" onChange={this.handleChange}type="text" value={this.state.first} />
      </div>
      <div className="row">
       <input name="last" onChange={this.handleChange}type="text" value={this.state.last} />
      </div>
      <div className="row">
       <input  name="submit" type="submit" />
      </div>
     </form>
    );
  }
}

const Display=(props)=>{
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="row">
        {props.name}
        </div>
        <div className="row">
        {props.last}
        </div>
      </div>
    )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why did you declare state in App and added handleSubmit method into it? Also what does this this.props.onSubmit(this.state.first, this.state.last); in handleSubmit in Form do? Why did you use props in this handleSubmit in Form? Can you just briefly explain the logic of using App and Form component please?

Comment: `App` component holds the state that is validated and submitted from the `Form`, only this needs to be displayed as in your requirement. The state that `Form` holds is the one you can use to validate till the user presses submit